# Get the form object without using name/ID

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a page that has many forms, they all have the same name. Within one of those forms I have a button that has an onClick function. One of those parameters needs to contain the form (so I can serialize it later) or a way to pass all the form parameters.

How do I get this done using only the onClick method (without binding an event handler to the submit event of the form).

note: My current work around has been to generate a random form name for each form (using PHP), then just passing that form as a parameter.

Comment: can you share the html of the form... a sample of the form and the onclick method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the input element you can get the form just by accessing the form property:

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].form);
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" />
</form>
```